# Spotify API top-tracks broken

Tags: json, node.js, spotify

I'm trying to get the first top-track preview url from an artist but everytime I do the search it returns a broken json. I can parse it as a string to get what I need but a json would be a lot easier. Here is my code:

```
const https = require('https');
var open = require('open')

function songError(){
    console.log('There was some kind of error fetching your artist ;(');
}

function getTopSong(p_id){
    https.get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/'+p_id+'/top-tracks?country=BR', function(res){
        res.on("data", function(chunk){
            var json = JSON.parse(chunk.toString('utf8'));
            console.log(json);
        });
    });
}

function getArtistID(p_name) {
    https.get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q='+encodeURI(p_name)+'&type=artist', function(res){
        res.on("data", function(chunk) {
            var json = JSON.parse(chunk.toString('utf8'));
            if(json['artists']['items'][0]['id'] != undefined || json['artists']['items'][0]['id'] != null){
                console.log('id: ',json['artists']['items'][0]['id']);
                getTopSong(json['artists']['items'][0]['id']);
            }else
            {
                songError();
            }
        });
    });
}

getArtistID("rage against the machine");
```

There seems to be an error in line 329:

```
undefined:329
  "available_markets" : [ "AR", "AU", "AT", "BE", "BO", "BR", "BG", "CA", "CL", "CO", "CR", "CY", "CZ", "DK", "DO", "DE", "EC", "EE", "SV", "FI", "FR", "GR", "
```

My question is, am I doing something wrong or is it really broken?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could curl it without any problems at least:

```
$ curl -s 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/2d0hyoQ5ynDBnkvAbJKORj/top-tracks?country=BR' | python -mjson.tool | tail
            "id": "25CbtOzU8Pn17SAaXFjIR3",
            "name": "Take The Power Back - Remastered",
            "popularity": 58,
            "preview_url": "https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/b44e8f96a219871587d0559970ca5dce71c891f2",
            "track_number": 3,
            "type": "track",
            "uri": "spotify:track:25CbtOzU8Pn17SAaXFjIR3"
        }
    ]
}
```

I don't know much about nodejs, but don't you need to concatenate all callbacks to res.on("data"?

https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback

```
https.get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/' + p_id + '/top-tracks?country=BR', function(res) {
  var body = [];
  res.on("data", function(chunk) {
    body.push(chunk);
  });
  res.on("end", function() {
    var json = JSON.parse(Buffer.concat(body).toString("utf8"));
    console.log(json);
  });
});
```

If the response is long and Spotify's servers decides to send the response back chunked transfer encoding, then the nodejs http module probably splits the response up as well.

Comment: That's it, I forgot to concatenate it all, silly mistake! thx!

Comment: And I just realized it probably has nothing to do with chunked transfer encoding from the server. The api will probably split the body into chunks anyway so you could download gigabytes without having to read everything into memory.